How to find ideals in $\mathbb Z[x]$ that contain $2$ and $x^7 - 1$?
This question came up as part of my assignment in the university. First off, here is the whole question for the bigger picture:
Classify all ideals of the Ring  $R := \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^7 -1)$, that contain the principal ideal 2R. (the principal ideal 2R is just the ideal generated by 2).
Here is what i have so far:
I am trying to use the bijection between the ideals of R and the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, that contain $(x^7-1)$. So I tried to find ideals of Z[X] that contain both $2$ and $(x^7-1)$, which is what brought me to the question of this post.
I realized very quickly that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not a principal ideal domain, so i can't just rely on Bezout's Lemma. I tried adding a few elements to my ideal to see how much i can add to it before i have the whole Ring and came to the following conclusion:
An Ideal $I$, that contains $2$ and $(x^7-1)$ should look something like this:
$I := <2,(x^7-1),f(x)>$ where we can assume without loss of generality that: $deg(f) \leq 6 $ and all coefficients of f are either $1$ or $0$. This can be achieved by adding multiples of $(x^7-1)$ and $2$ to f. But I don't know how to move forward from here? I could obviously just try out all possible polynomials for f, but that is definitely not the point of the exercise.
So to sum up, here is my question again: Is there a way to classify all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ that contain $2,(x^7-1)$?
I also study in German, so sorry in advance if I misused any terms or spelled anything incorrectly.

Using the correspondence of ideals in quotients the other way, the ideals you are looking for correspond to ideals of $\mathbb Z[X]/(2,X^7-1)$. Can you simplify this ring?

I think this isomorphism maybe helpful: $R / (I+J) \cong (R / J) / I$. Then you will end up with some quotient of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ - which is an Euclidean domain.

Thank you, that was very helpful! I think I should be able to classify all of them easily now :)

You will be needing the factorization of $x^7-1$ modulo two:
$$x^7-1\equiv (x+1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1).$$ Those cubics are irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$.
